# How to create an efficient immutable tree, with parent pointers

Tags: rust, tree, immutability, doubly-linked-list, unsafe

I'm constructing a "scenegraph", which is a hierarchical data structure of `Shape` nodes (e.g. sphere, cube, mesh, etc. not shown in example code). A `Shape` can own zero or more child `Shape` instances. This forms a tree, which is built fully and then passed immutably to a set of worker threads, that render separate parts of the image based on this scenegraph. There is no requirement for the scenegraph to change once it is built, so the threads only need read access.

[image: Example]

My question involves the construction of the scenegrape. Initially, I had Shapes that own sub-Shapes. I.e. A Shape owns all of its children. Therefore I was not using pointers or references. This worked fine until I needed to add parent pointers.

Each child of a `Shape` must now maintain a pointer to its parent. I went down the path of using `Arc` (because eventually the scenegraph is shared between threads), and that let's me use a `Weak` ptr to a parent to avoid the cycle problem. But the implication of this is that the primary owning relationship, where Shapes own sub-Shapes, now has to be an `Arc` too, and this pointer is traversed many, many more times than the parent pointer.

It is my understanding that the features of `Arc` are only necessary during construction of this data structure and handing over to the thread pool. During rendering these `Arc` pointers is unfortunate overhead. The data structure is considered immutable at this point, so the features of Arc are no longer needed. They were only required during the building of the data structure, to support the creation of `Weak` parent pointers.

Interestingly, I couldn't find a way in *safe* code to set a child as owned by a Shape *and* set the parent pointer in the child. It's a kind of doubly-linked list, which I know is difficult in Rust. In the end I had to use a single line of `unsafe` to set the pointer in `Shape::set_parent()` below:

```
use std::sync::{Arc, Weak};

pub trait LocalIntersect {
    fn local_intersect(&self);
}

#[derive(Debug, Default)]
pub struct Shape {
    id: usize,
    members: Vec<Arc<Shape>>,
    parent: Option<Weak<Shape>>,
}

impl Shape {
    fn new(id: usize) -> Self {
        Self { id, members: vec![], parent: None }
    }

    fn add(&mut self, shape: Arc<Shape>) {
        self.members.push(shape);
    }

    fn set_parent(&self, parent: Weak<Shape>) {
        let this = self as *const Shape as *mut Shape;
        unsafe {
            (*this).parent = Some(parent);
        }
    }

    fn set_parent_to_all(&self, parent_weak: Weak<Shape>) {
        for member in &self.members {
            member.set_parent(parent_weak.clone());
        }
    }
}

impl LocalIntersect for Shape {
    fn local_intersect(&self) {
        // For now, check if there is a parent and if so, print its ID
        // (Later, we'll combine parent transforms, but not now)
        if let Some(parent_weak) = &self.parent {
            if let Some(parent) = parent_weak.upgrade() {
                println!("local_intersect {}, parent {}", self.id, parent.id);
            }
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut parent_shape = Shape::new(0);
    let child_shape = Shape::new(1);

    let child_arc = Arc::new(child_shape);

    // Add child to the parent's group
    parent_shape.add(Arc::clone(&child_arc));

    // Wrap the parent shape in Arc
    let parent_arc = Arc::new(parent_shape);

    // Set the parent pointer of each child in the group
    parent_arc.set_parent_to_all(Arc::downgrade(&parent_arc));

    // Share across threads (example with a thread)
    let shared_node = Arc::clone(&child_arc);
    let thread = std::thread::spawn(move || {
        shared_node.local_intersect();
    });
    thread.join().unwrap();

    // Output is:
    //   local_intersect 1, parent 0
}
```

[Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=5778c8f5bf333bc5b1f5554d6fd8f80b)

Given performance is a top priority for this application, is there an idiomatic way to handle this in Rust? Is this a good candidate for `unsafe` code? Should I drop `Arc` and `Weak` and just use normal child ownership and a raw pointer for the parent pointer? If so, how would I handle the dropping of this data structure later?

I could use something like `id_tree` or `petgraph` however those will also provide an overhead when looking up children or parents. I really just want a pointer that the renderer can directly follow back to the parent, without affecting the performance of the very common "get child" look-up.

I'm not new to Rust or C/C++ but I am new to writing `unsafe` Rust code.

EDIT: For example, in a C program I’d just add a raw parent pointer to all sub-Shapes prior to rendering, and null them all out afterwards before deallocating any Shapes, and it wouldn’t affect ownership or cause a dangling pointer problem. I’m looking for a similar process in Rust - just a nice, simple, fast parent pointer in an eventually immutable data structure, but without the chicken-and-egg issues.

Comment: As with any `unsafe` you should run this under miri (top right on the playground under tools). Your code contains UB! It modifies code which is pointed at by a shared reference, you can't do that.

Comment: Well, you can if you can guarantee that the modification only ever happens in a single-threaded context, before it is handed off to the thread pool. It’s not UB unless called in a multithreaded context, yeah? Admittedly the unsafe function should document that. Anyway, I’d rather find a safe way to do it, I’m just not sure if there is one.

Comment: No, it's still not safe. The _only_ safe mechanism for mutating through a shared reference is `UnsafeCell`. The compiler is free to optimize as though your writes through the `self as *const Shape as *mut Shape` pointer never happened. However, you could trivially fix this by using `RefCell<Weak<Shape>>`.

Comment: @cdhowie can you comment on whether unsafe setting of the parent pointer is required in the first place? And if I use a `RefCell` how would I send the data structure to a thread after construction?

Comment: Note also that the `Option` in `Option<Weak<T>>` is entirely unnecessary. `Weak` implements `Default` and provides a `new()` constructor function that creates a new `Weak` without a backing `Arc`, meaning upgrading it will return `None`. Since `Weak` has a `None`-ness built in by its very nature, you don't need another layer.

Comment: Yeah, I suspected `Option<Weak<>>` was superfluous - thank you for confirming.

Comment: If you need thread safety with interior mutability, you need something like `RwLock`/`Mutex` to synchronize access to `parent`. You could also directly use `UnsafeCell<Weak<Shape>>` though then you need to make your `parent` accessors `unsafe` or otherwise provide a safe wrapping yourself.

Comment: @cdhowie my main requirement, I think, is to have interior mutability at the time I build the data structure, but not to have to pay that cost while treating the data structure as immutable later. I shouldn’t need to lock or access-count the data if I’m not changing it.

Comment: @davidA Right. There's a few ways you can accomplish that. Let me think on it a bit and then I can write an answer.

Comment: @davidA Would you consider an [arena](https://docs.rs/typed-arena/latest/typed_arena/) as a possible solution? This is the most straightforward way to have these kinds of graphs in Rust. This also makes all of the shapes contiguous in memory, which has advantages in terms of memory caching.

Comment: @davidA You may also be interested in [`Arc::new_cyclic`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Arc.html#method.new_cyclic).

Comment: @cdhowie the arena looks promising. So the pointers, including parent pointers, are just regular references? And this works because the lifetimes are all bundled together? I will consider this - thank you.

Comment: @davidA Yes. There are also other implementations of the arena concept that give you back an opaque "id" struct that, under the hood, is an index into the arena's pool of values. You can even roll one yourself as a `Vec`.

Comment: @cdhowie `Arc::new_cyclic` looks useful too. I will try putting together examples with both.

Comment: @cdhowie the issue with going through an index is that there’s an extra indirection during lookup, which is slower than just following a pointer. I’m trying to avoid that cost. I know I can use id_tree or petgraph if I didn’t worry about the performance effect.

Comment: `Arc` only has an overhead when it is created and dropped, not when it is dereferenced (`Arc` is basically a pointer + a thread-safe counter, so when you dereference it, it's like dereferencing the underlying pointer). So, before tearing your application apart with `unsafe`, you should check that you are noticing an overhead for using `Arc` *at all*.

Comment: Besides that, I think that arenas are particularly suited to your problem if you really need to squeeze performance, because not only they allocate contiguous chunks of memory, which is cache-friendly, but they actually allocate and deallocate through the memory allocator once, and their internal allocating strategy is very well suited for situations in which you start by allocating a lot of objects, then use them, then deallocate them all (as is, for instance, in compiler passes, or in rendering software).

Comment: @jthulhu upgrading `Weak` to `Arc` does have to create a `Arc` though.

Comment: @cafce25 yeah but in the question, it is said that the parent link is used much less often than the child link and, if I understood correctly, it's in the top-down traversal that the overhead is a problem ("But the implication of this is that the primary owning relationship, where Shapes own sub-Shapes, now has to be an Arc too, and this pointer is traversed many, many more times than the parent pointer.")

Comment: @jthulhu I don’t seem to be able to find a way to create an Arc to a child and a Weak to a parent though, as the two mutations conflict. The unsafe block was the only way I could find to do it, as it’s a chicken-and-egg problem I think. I can’t modify the parent to add the child’s Arc because creating the Weak ptr needs the Arc first to downgrade. I went around in circles and couldn’t find a sequence that worked for arbitrary trees. Happy to use and measure performance of Arcs if I could figure out how to get the data structure into place initially.

Comment: Yes I don’t mind traversing an Arc to child most of the time, and the Weak ptr to parent occasionally.

Comment: If I understand correctly, your problem is the double indirection with `Arc`, correct? Then I don't understand how your unsafe code solves this. Also, as already said, it contains UB. If the indirection is not the problem, you can use `Arc` and `Weak` with `new_cyclic()` or `get_mut()`. If it is the problem, this is a good use-case for unsafe (assuming you encapsulate the data structure with a public safe interface in its own module, perhaps even its own crate), but try to look for a crate that implements this pattern before implementing it yourself.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman `unsafe` was because I didn't know about `new_cyclic()` I think. I had a lot of trouble setting the parent pointer and adding the child to the parent, in the context of a tree where the parent is also owned by an `Arc`. I will look for existing implementations, for sure.

Comment: @cdhowie FWIW, I wasn't able to get a `typed_arena` to work, with shared references as child/parent "pointers", because the allocator function returns a _mutable_ reference to the new type instance, and this can't be converted to an immutable reference for a child or parent `Arc` (needed for the immutable sharing between threads part of the problem).

I was also not able to get a safe `Arc` / `Weak` solution working either. The only method that has worked so far is using a simple `Vec` with indices, but the extra indirection is still a concern.

I continue the learning process...

Answer (score 1):

If you really consider the tree as immutable once built, maybe could you pack all the nodes in a vector and work with indices instead of references (maybe this is called an arena, not sure if there is a subtlety).
We have to be extra-careful with the indices when building the tree, but this can be totally encapsulated in the implementation (we never have to assign an id ourselves).
In a multithreaded context, we just have to share/pass the vector of nodes as a whole.

Here is your example slightly transformed with this idea in mind.
(I didn't understand the `local_intersect()` function, maybe it does not do what you want).

```rust
use std::sync::Arc;

mod shape_tree {

    #[derive(Debug)]
    pub struct Shape {
        id: usize,
        members: Vec<usize>,
        parent_id: usize,
    }

    impl Shape {
        pub fn new(
            shapes: &mut Vec<Self>,
            parent_id: Option<usize>,
        ) -> usize {
            let id = shapes.len();
            shapes.push(Self {
                id,
                members: Vec::new(),
                parent_id: usize::MAX,
            });
            if let Some(parent_id) = parent_id {
                shapes[parent_id].members.push(id);
                shapes[id].parent_id = parent_id;
            };
            id
        }

        pub fn id(&self) -> usize {
            self.id
        }

        pub fn members(&self) -> &[usize] {
            &self.members
        }

        pub fn parent<'a>(
            &self,
            shapes: &'a [Self],
        ) -> Option<&'a Self> {
            if self.parent_id == usize::MAX {
                None
            } else {
                Some(&shapes[self.parent_id])
            }
        }
    }
}

pub trait LocalIntersect {
    fn local_intersect(
        &self,
        shapes: &[shape_tree::Shape],
    );
}

impl LocalIntersect for shape_tree::Shape {
    fn local_intersect(
        &self,
        shapes: &[shape_tree::Shape],
    ) {
        // For now, check if there is a parent and if so, print its ID
        // (Later, we'll combine parent transforms, but not now)
        if let Some(parent) = self.parent(shapes) {
            println!("local_intersect {}, parent {}", self.id(), parent.id());
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut shapes = Vec::new();
    let parent_id = shape_tree::Shape::new(&mut shapes, None);
    let child_id = shape_tree::Shape::new(&mut shapes, Some(parent_id));
    let shapes = Arc::new(shapes.into_boxed_slice()); // seal the vector

    let thread = std::thread::spawn({
        let shapes = Arc::clone(&shapes);
        move || {
            println!("in thread");
            shapes[child_id].local_intersect(&shapes);
        }
    });
    thread.join().unwrap();

    println!("back to main");
    shapes[child_id].local_intersect(&shapes);
}
/*
in thread
local_intersect 1, parent 0
back to main
local_intersect 1, parent 0
*/
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. `local_intersect()` was just a hold-over from my code, and in my example I just had it demonstrating that the parent pointer is available and usable when running a function on a Shape. I like this arena idea a lot, but I am a bit concerned about the extra indirection that this introduces - doesn't each access into the arena involve both a pointer to the vector, and then pointer arithmetic to the offset? I do wonder in practice how much of an effect that would actually have though, and it might be completely mitigated by proximity keeping the CPU cache warm. Worth a try!